# Migrating wordpress

Tags: wordpress, migration, hosting

I am trying to migrate a Wordpress website from one hosting to another one. In the new hosting I can see it correctly if I access it from localhost, but if I try to render the web from an exteral pc, the .css and the images are not loaded (you can see it here 91.121.122.50/wp

Note that the link to the images points correctly (if you copy-paste the url of any image and open in a new window, it will load)

The new host has been configurated for a user, so I think it is a etc/hosts, apache2 or php configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can either update the database

```
//FIXME: do comment/remove these hack lines. (once the database is updated)
update_option('siteurl', 'http://your.domain.name/the/path' );
update_option('home', 'http://your.domain.name/the/path' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

or place the folowing in you wp-config

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

In order to make all links working you've to update your htaccess in your admin area under settings -> permalinks.

Comment: Check if your stylesheets, scripts etc. are linked correctly in your theme files E.g. With the wordpress blog info method

Comment: I think they are linked correctly. Also, if that were the issue, i wouldn't be able to see the site correctly from localhost, right?

Comment: When I see your website in the chrome resources tab I see some weird ORT - Ovh Redirect Technology redirect page on your css and scripts. Your defaults.css links to http://ks3329896.kimsufi.com/wp/wp-content/themes/gaming-black/lib/css/defaults.css maybe the problem is with the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

There is a WordPress plugin called duplicator. Using this plugin we can transfer WordPress website from one host to another. I think this is the simple and easy way to transfer WordPress sit. [Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) is the link.